# Android AVD-Unabe to rotate landscape/portrait

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I want to rotate landscape/portrait android emulator.
I found that I should Do one of this options:
1-Pressing numpad7 as the Num Lock is Off
2-Pressing Ctrl and F11
3-Pressing Ctrl and F12
Here is the emulator when I start it:
[Here is the emulator when I start it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQkYK.png)
I pressed numpad7:No change!
I pressed Ctrl and F11:It goes to multi-touch mode,I want just rotating!
Here is when I press Ctrl and F11 or Ctrl and F12:
[Here is when I press Ctrl and F11 or Ctrl and F12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqpBl.png)
I checked the sensors availability.All were Ok:
acceleration: enabled.
magnetic-field: enabled.
orientation: enabled.
temperature: enabled.                                                                              proximity: enabled.                                                                                                    light: enabled.
pressure: enabled.
humidity: enabled.

I didn't find any good idea to solve my problem.So I'm Here on StackOverFlow.
What should I do?

Sorry for my bad English
Thanks.

Comment: Pleaaaseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee help if you can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Ctrl+Left and Ctrl+Right

If you need do it with Appium on Java, this comands work for me:

```
((AppiumDriver) driver)
            .rotate(ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE);

((AppiumDriver) driver)
            .rotate(ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT);
```